# Proving continuity of $\|DG(x)y\|$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Suppose Let $U\subset \mathbb R^m$ be open and $u\in U$. Let $s>0$ and $A:=B_s(u) \subset \mathbb R^m$, where $B_s(a)$ denotes the closed ball of radius of $s$ about $u$. Suppose that $G: A \to \mathbb R^m$ is $C^1$. For each $x\in A$, let $DG(x)$ be the Jacobian of $G$ evaluated at $x$. Assume that $DG(x)$ is invertible for each $x$ in $A$.

Now consider the function $f:  A \times S^{m-1}\to \mathbb R^m$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto \|DG(x)y\|$.

I know that matrix multiplication is linear in general, but since the matrix in this situation depends on $x$ where $x$ is a variable, we cannot hold $DG(x)$ fixed. Therefore, I'm not sure if $f$ is continuous.

I realize that it would be sufficient to prove the map $(x,y)\mapsto DG(x)y$ is continuous, but I don't know if we necessarily can do this.

Could someone explain why or why not $f$ is continuous?

Comment: if you dont have any hypothesis on $L$ I am pretty sure that $f$ may be discontinuous.

Comment: Certainly can be false if $L$ fails to be continuous, you need more information.

Comment: @AdamHughes Yeah, I see. Out of curiosity, it I changed $f$ to the map $(x,y)\mapsto \|L(x)y\|$, would we get continuity?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 no, the same issue occurs, if $L(x)$ jumps at any point to something of eg. larger norm then you're completely out of luck.

Comment: @AdamHughes Got it. I added several additional hypotheses that may fix the issue, but I could definitely still be wrong.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 perhaps you could add a bit more context, this certainly no longer closely resembles your original question. I can tell you that if $L:\Bbb R^m\to M_{m\times m}(\Bbb R)$ is continuous then $(x,y)\mapsto L(x)y$ is continuous, which is a very general statement without a lot of the muck. The only thing lacking in your original hypotheses was continuity of $L$.

Comment: @AdamHughes The context is just me playing around with some problems/scenarios while studying for an exam. I'd like to avoid outright assuming continuity of $L$. Would having that $DG(x)$ is invertible help?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 I mean, $C^1$ implies continuous, the fact that you restrict the domain doesn't particularly help you, in fact both this and an invertible Jacobian are **stronger** assumptions, so you're assuming continuity already, even if you're not saying it out loud.

Comment: @AdamHughes I'm assuming continuity of $G$, but this is not the same as the function $L$ that you wrote. (The confusion may be due to my editing my question a lot.)

Comment: @CuriousKid7 so is $L$ just gone then? I ask because the original question--assuming continuity of $L$--is a weaker assumption than the one you have written here.

Additionally, it should be stated: the kind of extreme specificity without a clear goal and more playing around isn't likely going to get you a thorough, high-level answer as it's likely far too niche. If you're interested I recommend toying around with it on your own with specific cases, but without that it's a bit too awkward to treat systematically without outside motivation. (Just friendly advice) :)

Comment: @AdamHughes Are you saying that the additional assumptions of my current question imply that the function $L:\mathbb R^m \to M_{m\times m}(\mathbb R)$ is continuous? You seem to say that this is because of my new assumption that the function $G$ is $C^1$ (hence continuous). But I don't see how the continuity of $G$ implies the continuity of the map $x\mapsto DG(x)$. Alternatively, you've said the invertibility of $DG(x)$ is a stronger assumption. I also don't know why this is the case. How does the fact that $DG(x)$ is invertible for each $x\in A$ imply $x\mapsto DG(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 I no longer see any connection to $L$, but you are instead of asking about a general $L$ you have gotten more specific so that for $x,y$ you are asking if $\lVert DG(x)y\rVert$ is continuous, but if you map that back, $DG$ is clearly taking the place of $L$ and the $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is thrown in to make it even more likely to be continuous. If you assume all of that, you--in particular--would know that $DG= L $ was continuous which is all you need. So you say you want to **avoid** $L$ being continuous, but the only thing even related to $L$ is **automatically** continuous

Comment: @CuriousKid7 In particular it's a strange way to change the question, as it appears you're sabotaging yourself since you're automatically assuming continuity of the only thing related to your original idea when you say you want to not assume that.

Comment: @AdamHughes Ok, forget about $L$. You say that I know that the map $x\mapsto DG(x)$ is continuous. But I'm just assuming that $G$ is continuous (or $C^1$, whatever) and $DG(x)$ is invertible. How can I conclude from these assumption that $x\mapsto DG(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: Composition of continuous functions is continuous, so it's automatic

Comment: @AdamHughes Wow, I'm sorry for the confusion. I see I was just missing something simple. Thanks for your patience with that issue. Last thing: now that we know $x\mapsto DG(x)$ is continuous, you said we can conclude $DG(x)y$ is continuous. What facts justify this conclusion exactly?

Comment: That matrix multiplication is continuous requires a bit of proof, but it's not difficult. It just amounts to the fact that matrix multiplication is fundamentally a polynomial map in each coordinate and polynomials are continuous

Comment: @AdamHughes Right, thank you so much